# ¿Cómo calcular precio de energía?

Tags: python

Escriba un programa que calcule el precio a pagar por el suministro de energía eléctrica. Pregunte la cantidad de kwh consumida y el tipo de instalación: R para residencias, I para industrias y C para comercios. Calcule el precio a pagar de acuerdo con la siguiente tabla.

```
residencia = 'residencias'
industria = 'industrias'
comercio = 'comercios'
kwh_consumida = float(input('Cantidad de kwg consumida: '))
instalacion = input('tipo de instalacion: ')

if residencia <= 500:
      precio = 50
elif residencia > 500:
      precio = 65   
elif comercio < 1000:
      precio = 55
elif comercio > 1000:
      precio = 60  
elif industria < 5000:
      precio = 0.55
elif industria > 5000:
      precio = 60
else:
    print('¿Categoria invalida?')
    precio = 0
```

No puedo usar una funcion (`def`) por que aun no he llegado a ver ese punto aun, si alguien me podría dar la solución de por que no funciona se lo agradecería un montón, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Hay que arreglar un poco el código.

Aquí ingresas el tipo de instalación (R, C, o I):

```
instalacion = input('tipo de instalacion: ')
```

pero nunca usas esa información, que debería ser aplicada así:

```
if instalacion == 'R':
    if kwh_consumida <= 500:
        precio = 50
    else:
        precio = 65
```

Primero se pregunta por el tipo de instalación y luego por el consumo. Como la tabla es simple, basta con un `if-else` para asignar el precio; no es necesario hacer dos comparaciones.

Finalmente, hay que usar el precio, siempre que sea distinto de cero:

```
if precio:
    print("Precio=", precio)
```

**Demo**

```
kwh_consumida = float(input('Cantidad de kwg consumida: '))
instalacion = input('tipo de instalacion: ')

if instalacion == 'R':
    if kwh_consumida <= 500:
        precio = 50
    else:
        precio = 65
elif instalacion == 'C':
    if kwh_consumida < 1000:
        precio = 55
    else:
        precio = 60
elif instalacion == 'I':
    if kwh_consumida < 5000:
        precio = 0.55
    else:
        precio = 60
else:
    print('¿Categoria invalida?')
    precio = 0

if precio:
    print("Precio=", precio)
```

produce

```
Cantidad de kwg consumida: 40
tipo de instalacion: C
Precio= 55

Process finished with exit code 0
```